# Creating a UIWebView when a cell is selected in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, ios4

I have the following code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIWebView *aWebView;
    aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];//init and create the UIWebView
    aWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    aWebView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
    //set the web view delegates for the web view to be itself
    [aWebView setDelegate:self];
    //Set the URL to go to for your UIWebView
    NSString *urlAddress = @"www.google.com";
    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //load the URL into the web view.
    [aWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
    //add the web view to the content view
    [self.view addSubview:aWebView];

}
```

On click of any of the cells it should create a UIWebView and goto google.com but for some reason I get the following error : `2011-12-04 23:47:56.825 AudStud[906:207] Unknown scheme, doing nothing: www.google.com`

Comment: Try changing your URL to `http://www.google.com`, and adding your UIWebView to the view before invoking `loadRequest:`.

Comment: You have a memory leak, release aWebView after addSubview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is missing the protocol part. It should be `http://www.google.com`.